# Using deleteRow when passing a parameter using Google Sheets with Client-side & Server-side

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, parameter-passing, delete-row

I am using Google's Web Apps for this code and I am a true novice when it comes to javascript. The way it works is that the user enters an id and once they click the delete button the value is passed to the server-side. Before it deletes I want it to copy the row over to another tab (that works) and then proceed to delete the row which is not working. Thanks in advance for the help. Below is the server side code.

```
function removeRecord(dataInfo) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
    var source = ss.getSheetByName("Table");
    var target = ss.getSheetByName("Deleted");
    var data = source.getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow()-1, source.getLastColumn()).getValues();


    var id = data.map(function (r) { return r[0]; });
    
    var pos = id.indexOf(dataInfo);
    
    
    if (pos > -1) {
      target.appendRow(data[pos]);
      source.deleteRow(data[pos]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: You completely got it right.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the argument of `deleteRow(rowPosition)` is the integer number. But, in your script, an array is used. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. In the case of your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
source.deleteRow(data[pos]);
```

#### To:

```
source.deleteRow(pos + 2);
```

#### Note:

- From `I am using Google's Web Apps`, **when you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- As another approach, in your script, the following modification might be able to be used. In this case, [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) is used. By this, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little. By the way, in this script and the above modification, it supposes that `dataInfo` is the valid value. Please be careful about this.

  ```js
  function removeRecord(dataInfo) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
    var source = ss.getSheetByName("Table");
    var search = source.getRange("A2:A" + source.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(dataInfo).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
    if (!search) return;
    var target = ss.getSheetByName("Deleted");
    search.offset(0, 0, 1, source.getLastColumn()).copyTo(target.getRange(target.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });
    source.deleteRow(search.getRow());
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [deleteRow(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)

Comment: thanks for the response, sorry been in meetings all day and just saw it. There id data validation on the client-side of what the user is entering. The data passes over after confirmation that the user wants to delete the record.  The value of that record ID is then passed over to dataInfo.  I think you understood my question and thanks for the response.

Comment: it worked!  Thanks. Would you mind explaining why I needed to do (pos +2)?

Comment: In addition, the second approach worked as well.

Comment: @Berryblue Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `Would you mind explaining why I needed to do (pos +2)?`, in your script, `pos` is retrieved by `var pos = id.indexOf(dataInfo);`. By this, the searched row can be found. About `2`, this is an offset `2` of `getRange(2, 1, source.getLastRow()-1, source.getLastColumn())`. By this, the row number can be obtained. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.